# A cellular automaton with an image that is not closed

Tags: gr.group-theory, gn.general-topology, automata-theory, cellular-automata

Let $G$ be a non-locally finite periodic group and let $V$ be an infinite-dimensional vector space over a field $\mathbb{F}$. Does there exist a nontrivial topology on $V^G$ and a linear cellular automaton $\tau : V^G\longrightarrow V^G$ whose image is not closed in $V^G$ with respect to that topology?

The motivation arises from the point that in the case of prodiscrete topology on $V^G$, it is not found any cellular automaton yet. Ceccherini-Silberstein  and Coornaert have shown that if any of the above assumptions is omitted, then there is a linear cellular automaton $\tau$ such that $Im(\tau)$ is closed in $V^G$ with respect to prodiscrete topology.

Comment: Don't you even have examples on just V? I.e. nbhd size 1.

Comment: V is a set of colors or alphabets in Cellular Automata theory, for example take colors black and white @VilleSalo

Comment: I know, I meant if V is infinite-dimensional, then isn't there an example where nbhd size is one and image is not closed?

Comment: I didn't see such an example.@VilleSalo

Comment: If $\mathbb{F}$ is the reals and the dimension of $V$ is $2^{\aleph_0}$, then you can give $V$ the structure of a Hilbert space, take the usual example of a linear map $f : V \to V$ whose image is not closed, and then have it act cellwise. I don't know what the exact situtions are when an infinite-dimensional vector space admits a non-trivial topology such that some linear map does not have closed image. This depends on what you mean by "non-trivial", I assume you don't just mean "not the trivial topology".

Comment: By the way, cannot we divide the infinite cardinality of $V$ by $|G|$, and simulate cellular automata inside it, and conclude that an example like you seek exists if and only if $V$ already admits a non-trivial topology and a linear endomorphism with non-closed image?